# Need help create wpf listview custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I want to create a WPF custom control inherit ListView. I know how to build the listview in a normal WPF window but in custom control's Generic.xaml I don't know how to do it.
Can you help me transform the listview below into custom control's Generic.xaml format please?
Thanks.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyListViewItemContainerStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" >
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstColumnDataTemplate" >
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Margin="-6,0,-6,0">
                <Grid Margin="6,2,6,2">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding FirstColumnItemTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomControl1}}" 
                                      Focusable="False" 
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SecondColumnDataTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFABADB3" BorderThickness="0,0,1,1" Margin="-6,0,-6,0">
                <Grid Margin="6,2,6,2">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding SecondColumnItemTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:CustomControl1}}" 
                                      Focusable="False" 
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="MyListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-4,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="FirstColumn"
                            Header="{TemplateBinding FirstColumnHeader}"
                            CellTemplate="{DynamicResource FirstColumnDataTemplate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="SecondColumn"
                            Header="{TemplateBinding SecondColumnHeader}" 
                            CellTemplate="{DynamicResource SecondColumnDataTemplate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

FirstColumnHeader, SecondColumnHeader are string dependency properties.  FirstColumnItemTemplate, SecondColumnItemTemplate are DataTemplate dependency properties of the custom control.
The custom control itself inherit ListView like:

```
public class CustomControl1 : ListView
```

Comment: https://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

Did you even try to search online?

Comment: @Mishka please read my post, it's how to build a custom control inherit ListView, like I mentioned in the bottom of post. not how to build a custom control.

Comment: I have. Why do you think there is a difference? It's the same principle. And the link I gave you put light on exactly what you need to do.